# Post list display year wise

Tags: posts

It's possible wordpress single category post display year wise 
for example:

**2014** 
 Post1 
 Post2 
 Post3

**2013** 
 Post4 
 post5

**2012** 
 Post6 
 Post7

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to just list out links to the posts on single category post or are you trying to make the category archive of posts list the posts in a specific order?

Comment: Just show list out links to the posts on single category post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like recommending a plugin, but this plugin does exactly what you need, and it is the easiest way to go.

Just before I start, I would like to state that I don't have any affiliation regarding the plugin or its authors, nor am I marketing or trying to market the plugin in any way.

OK, that out of the way, you should download and install the [Simple Yearly Archive](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-yearly-archive/) plugin. I quote from the plugin page

> Simple Yearly Archive is a rather neat and simple WordPress plugin that allows you to display your archives in a year-based list. It works mostly like the usual WP archive, but displays all published posts seperated by their year of publication. That said, it’s also possible to restrict the output to certain categories, and much more

The how-to-use page can be found [here](http://www.schloebe.de/wordpress/simple-yearly-archive-plugin/).